Подсказать как стилизовать блок

Есть такой блок как на первой картинке. Хочу добавить в правом верхнем углу картинку которая будет выходить за края блока. Как кнопочка с телефоном внизу. Подскажите начинающему как мне это реализовать?
Нужно чтобы было адаптивно. Чтобы текст обтекал картинку при уменьшении размера экрана. Абсолютное позиционирование не подойдет. Float тоже не подойдет. При float картинку нельзя будет сместить за края блока. Я так понимаю.



добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! как задать хороший вопрос

Почему абсолютное позиционирование не подойдет? По-моему, оно существует как раз для этих целей.

"При float картинку нельзя будет сместить за края блока." Откуда такая уверенность?

Спасибо. Точно. Попробовал float. Все работает. Просто прочитал в интернете, что отрицательный margin при float не работает.

@ronga, не забывайте, есть ещё и transform: translate()

Я сделал пустой div с float, чтобы текст обтекал его. А поверх него сделал абсолютно позиционированную картинку.

Для блока нужно задать position: relative;, а для иконки и картинки в верхнем правом углу position: absolute;, и соответствующим образом позиционировать по вертикали и горизонтали.
Пример:


.block {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.image {
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px;
  right: -5px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  bacrground-color: #008000;
}

.icon {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -5px;
  right: -5px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #ff0000;
}
<div class="block">
  <div class="image"></div>
  <div class="icon"></div>
</div>




Спасибо. Я уже сделал как писал выше. То что вы предлагаете не совсем подойдет. При уменьшении экрана картинка и текст налазят друг не друга.

"При уменьшении экрана картинка и текст налазят друг не друга" - чтобы этого не происходило нужно использовать медиа-запросы для разных разрешений экрана https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_media_queries/Using_media_queries
